# Hybrid website hosting and load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, load-balancing

I am planning on moving our website to the cloud (AWS).
However this is going to be a big endeavor so i will migrate pages in different tempos.

On prem I have a number of servers behind a load balancer (netscaler).

When moving for instance the front page to AWS, where should I place the load balancer on prem or AWS?
Is it at all feasible to have one website hosted in AWS **and** on prem with the latency the load balancer would have to the part located the furthest away?

For instance if i have page1 hosted on prem and page 2 hosted in AWS and the load balancer hosted on prem, an end user would have a latency to the on prem load balancer, and the load balancer would have latency to the AWS page 2 service - that could double the latency
And vice verse.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Application load balancer ELB supports IP Targets, which means you can use your on-premise servers as a target for some specific pages

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/

with aws application load balancer you can also define rules, for example you can configure specific URI to be routing to your on-premise target group

Comment: Yup I get that it is possible, but would the latency kill the idea?

Comment: if you're worried much about latency you can set up an  AWS Direct Connect  that can give you very low latency